# Asterisk Call File Call failed to go through

Tags: asterisk, channel

With some basic Asterisk configuration, I'm trying to generate an autodial file. Although this call script works perfectly fine for internal numbers, trying the same for an external number leads to the following error:

```
Attempting call on SIP/provider/0049176xxxxxxx for 0049176xxxxxx@outgoing_spidey:1 (Retry 1)
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Called provider/0049176xxxxxx
    -- Got SIP response 603 "Decline" back from 9xx.1xx.1xx.2xx:5060
    -- SIP/provider-00000000 is busy
[Feb 20 12:16:37] NOTICE[32721]: pbx_spool.c:413 attempt_thread: Call failed to go through, reason (5) Remote end is Busy
```

The call file has a simple task to do:

- call the number
- deliver a message
- hangup

Destination of call file:
/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing

Call file (test.call):

```
Channel: SIP/provider/0049176xxxxxx
CallerID: 0221223366
MaxRetries: 1
RetryTime: 600
WaitTime: 30
Context: outgoing_spidey
Extension: 0049176xxxxxx
Priority: 1
```

Sip.conf

```
[provider]
        type=friend
        context=provider
        allow=ulaw,alaw
        secret=xxxxxx
        host=sip.xxxxx.com
        nat=force_rport,comedia
        insecure=invite
        fromdomain=sip.xxx.com
        defaultuser=sipuser
```

Extension.conf

```
[outgoing_spidey]
        exten => _X.,1,Answer()
        exten => _X.,n,Wait(2)
        exten => _X.,n,Playback(tt-monkeysintro)
        exten => _X.,n,Hangup()
```

Have done my best to google for any closest answer, but all in vain. Therefore, I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: Try another external number, if not check with your `host=sip.xxxxx.com` gateway provider why its getting busy signal. This doesn't seem to be asterisk issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A deeper look into the debug error message made things more clear.

```
Got SIP response 603 "Decline"
```

There is no mistake in the scripts, I've mentioned (in my question). The debug error says that Asterisk tries to make a call using SIP provider details but in return gets a negative response.

I got the problem solved by contacting the SIP Provider. However, the research I had to do to rectify the error has given me an immense understanding of Asterisk system.

Hope this might help some beginners, who face similar problem.